# Multiclass Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost

I have a Multi class classification problem( anonymised features) with 3 classes.Class 1 is being differentiated from other classes but I have a problem separating Class 2 from Class 0.(Most of the Class 2 is being predicted as Class 0).

Since there is a imbalance between these two classes (3:1) .I tried giving weights to Class 2 but then the model just classifies some of the Class 2 correctly but it also predicts Class 0 as Class 2 now, giving me the same accuracy when where was no weights given.

So any ideas on how to separate these two classes? I have tried NN, oneVSrest, also tried a bit of stacking with no significant gain.

Comment: Without the samples of data, and more description its hard to say. Anyways, this question will be more suitable for https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I used to face the imbalanced dataset before. I used the resample function from sklearn, You can read more from [here](https://elitedatascience.com/imbalanced-classes). The function will randomly copy from the minority to upsampling. In my experience, this method only slightly improve the model, I think you should find data on the internet to add into your dataset.

Comment: I just tried up and down sampling but that doesn't seem to work as well.The model is just randomly predicting 0 and 2's and projecting an accuracy of 50%.Now I think the problem is the two classes are not separable and the features being anonymised also is not helping.Any ideas to even predict some of the Class 2 correctly?

Comment: Yeah, The bias problem is definitively because there are not enough data for it to learn. If a new data which the model never see before, It will bias towards the minority class in the data. To be honest, I solve this problem by keep add more new data which I found on the internet, not just up-sampling or down-sampling the old data. In your case, I thinks you should up-sampling rather than down-sampling as you need more data which has minority label. If up-sampling not working, try deep random forest. I heard that It is a good model for unbalance dataset as Its parameter turning automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the binary logistic regression approach considering one vs rest, u will be getting 3 models. consider max of 3 probabilities and check accuracy. sometimes this approach works well.